# Facing and issues while running an old version code of flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am encountering an error while trying to build my Flutter APK using the flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety command. The error message indicates issues related to null safety in certain packages, including syncfusion_flutter_core, syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer, and horizontal_data_table. The project was developed using dart 2 sdk and some packages are not compatible with dart 3. So I downgrade the sdk version in my computer. But still facing an issue while generating an apk.

> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_core-20.4.54/lib/src/widgets/interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:59:9: Error: Type 'PanAxis' not found.
> final PanAxis panAxis;
> ^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_core-20.4.54/lib/src/widgets/interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:15:22: Error: Undefined name 'PanAxis'.
> this.panAxis = PanAxis.free,
> ^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-20.4.54/lib/src/pdfviewer.dart:1016:54: Error: Method 'readState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null.- 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
> Try calling using ?. instead.
> final dynamic offset = PageStorage.of(context).readState(context);
> ^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-20.4.54/lib/src/pdfviewer.dart:1020:12: Error: Method 'readState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null. - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
> Try calling using ?. instead.
> .readState(context, identifier: 'zoomLevel_${widget.key}');
> ^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-20.4.54/lib/src/pdfviewer.dart:3247:35: Error: Method 'writeState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null. - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
> Try calling using ?. instead.
> PageStorage.of(context).writeState(
> ^^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-20.4.54/lib/src/pdfviewer.dart:3275:35: Error: Method 'writeState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null. - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
> Try calling using ?. instead.
> PageStorage.of(context).writeState(
> ^^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/indicator/waterdrop_header.dart:159:46: Error: Property 'axisDirection' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null. - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> Scrollable.of(context).axisDirection == AxisDirection.up
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/indicator/waterdrop_header.dart:165:46: Error: Property 'axisDirection' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null. - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> Scrollable.of(context).axisDirection == AxisDirection.up
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/indicator/waterdrop_header.dart:169:46: Error: Property 'axisDirection' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null. - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> Scrollable.of(context).axisDirection == AxisDirection.up
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/internals/indicator_wrap.dart:335:42: Error: Property 'axisDirection' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null. - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> Scrollable.of(context).axisDirection == AxisDirection.up
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/internals/indicator_wrap.dart:390:43: Error: Property 'position' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null.  - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> if (mounted) Scrollable.of(context).position.correctBy(0.00001);
> ^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/internals/indicator_wrap.dart:630:63: Error: Property 'position' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null. - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> final ScrollPosition newPosition = Scrollable.of(context).position;
> ^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/indicator/material_indicator.dart:74:45: Error: Property 'position' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null.  - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> if (mounted && Scrollable.of(context).position.pixels <= 0)
> ^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/horizontal_data_table-4.1.4+1/lib/refresh/pull_to_refresh/src/internals/slivers.dart:182:30: Error: Property 'position' cannot be accessed on 'ScrollableState?' because it is potentially null. 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
> Try accessing using ?. instead.
> Scrollable.of(context).position.activity!.applyNewDimensions();
> ^^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_core-20.4.54/lib/src/widgets/interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:59:9: Error: 'PanAxis' isn't a type.
> final PanAxis panAxis;
> ^^^^^^^
> /home/osama/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_core-20.4.54/lib/src/widgets/interactive_scroll_viewer.dart:299:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'panAxis'.
> panAxis: widget.panAxis,
> ^^^^^^^
> ../../../../../snap/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/interactive_viewer.dart:61:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> InteractiveViewer({
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

below is the code of pubspec.yaml file

```html
name: nexthour
description: A Video Streaming Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  chewie: ^1.3.6
  unity_ads_plugin: ^0.3.7
  upi_india: ^3.0.1
  animated_text_kit: 4.2.2
  audioplayers: ^1.1.1
  facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.6
  video_player: ^2.4.7

  better_player: 0.0.83
  
  cashfree_pg: ^2.0.12+32
  flutterwave_standard: ^1.0.6
  payu_web_checkout: ^1.0.3
  payhere_mobilesdk_flutter: ^3.0.4
  file_picker: ^5.2.2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_translate: ^4.0.3
  loading_overlay: ^0.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  provider: ^6.0.4
  http: ^0.13.5
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  sticky_headers: ^0.3.0+2
#  fluttertoast: ^8.1.1.
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1

  # Old Version but do not upgrade it.
  intro_slider: ^3.0.2

  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
  sqflite: ^2.2.0+3
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer:
  #syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^20.4.53
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^6.0.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  share_plus: ^6.2.0
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  page_transition: ^2.0.9

  # Old Version but do not upgrade it.
  flutter_downloader: 1.8.0

  wakelock: ^0.6.2
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  rating_bar: ^0.2.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.1
  bubble_tab_indicator: ^0.1.6
  open_iconic_flutter: ^0.3.0
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  flutter_braintree: ^2.3.1
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.4
  paytm: ^3.0.1
  flutter_paystack: ^1.0.7
  in_app_update: ^3.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.6
  flutter_inapp_purchase: 5.3.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  dart_ipify: ^1.1.1
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  connectivity_plus_web: ^1.2.5
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.4.2

  # Old Versions but do not upgrade these.
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.8.5
  just_audio: 0.9.29

  firebase_messaging: ^14.0.4
  http_auth: ^1.0.1
  currencies: ^0.1.1
  flutter_credit_card: ^3.0.4
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.4
  google_mobile_ads: ^2.3.0
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
  flutter_lwa: ^2.0.0
  horizontal_data_table: 
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.1
  android_path_provider: ^0.3.0
  device_info_plus: ^8.0.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  collection: ^1.16.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/i18n/
    - assets/
    - icons/
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

le code